# excel vba read date as dd/mm/yyy

Tags: vba, excel, date

I have an Excel VBA code that retrieves data from an external workbook into a worksheet by month.

I would like to retrieve the month of November but I can't seem to type the date to be #30/11/2017#. The date would automatically change to #11/30/2017#.

The date has to be in dd/mm/yyyy as that is the format of date in the external workbook.

```
Sub zz()
Dim arr, c, b(), n&
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A6").AutoFilter
Workbooks.Open "C:\Users\sophia.tan\Desktop\excel masterplan\External 
workbook.xlsx", 0, 1
arr = Sheets("MaximMainTable").UsedRange
ActiveWorkbook.Close 0
c = Array(0, 2, 12, 13, 6, 7, 10, 1, 8, 9, 15, 16, 18, 19, 14, 27, 24, 25, 
26, 3, 4, 36)
d = Array(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 
20, 21, 23)
ReDim b(1 To UBound(arr), 1 To 23)
Selection.NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
For i = 2 To UBound(arr)
If arr(i, 12) >= (#1/11/2017#) And arr(i, 12) <= Format(#11/30/2017#) Then
    n = n + 1
    For j = 1 To UBound(c)
        b(n, d(j)) = arr(i, c(j))
    Next
End If
Next

Dim startRow As Long, lastRow2 As Long
startRow = 6
lastRow = Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = startRow To lastRow

If Range("A" & i) Like "MX*" Then

    If Range("J" & i) Like "*Rib*" Then
         Range("M" & i) = "Rib"

    ElseIf Range("J" & i) Like "*Spandex*Pique*" Then
         Range("M" & i) = "Spandex Pique"

    ElseIf ("J" & i) Like "*Pique*" Then
         Range("M" & i) = "Pique"

    ElseIf ("J" & i) Like "*Spandex*Jersey*" Then
         Range("M" & i) = "Spandex Jersey"

    ElseIf Range("J" & i) Like "*Jersey*" Then
         Range("M" & i) = "Jersey"

    ElseIf ("J" & i) Like "*Interlock*" Then
         Range("M" & i) = "Interlock"

    ElseIf ("J" & i) Like "*French*Terry*" Then
         Range("M" & i) = "Fleece"

    ElseIf ("J" & i) Like "*Fleece*" Then
         Range("M" & i) = "Fleece"

    Else


     Range("M" & i) = "Collar & Cuff"


    End If
    End If

 Next
 With Worksheets("Sheet2")
 .Range("A6:T" & Rows.Count).CurrentRegion.AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:="
 <>OFM"
 .Range("A6:T" & 
 Rows.Count).CurrentRegion.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).AutoFilter 
 field:=13, Criteria1:="<>Collar & Cuff"
 .Range("A6:T" & Rows.Count).CurrentRegion.Offset(1, 
 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
 .Range("A6").Resize(n, 23) = b
 .Range("A5").CurrentRegion.Sort key1:=Range("G5"), order1:=xlAscending, 
  Header:=xlYes


 End With



 Application.ScreenUpdating = 1

 End Sub
```

Comment: What happened when you tried it using the '#MDY#' entry in VBA?  If your external workbook is Excel, and if the dates are "real" dates, and not string representations, then the value is stored as a decimal value representing days and fractions of a day since 1 Jan 1900.  The format on the worksheet and the method of entering a date into VBA shouldn't make a difference.

Comment: when i use #MDY#, the records for december ae also copied over

Comment: This code `If arr(i, 12) >= (#1/11/2017#) And arr(i, 12) <= Format(#11/30/2017#) Then` compares the contents of `arr(i,12)` to a `Date` datatype and a  `String` datatype.  Not surprising that it may return unexpected results.  Why are you doing that?  Comparisons should usually be of the same datatype on both sides of the comparison operator.

Comment: Also, in your comparison line, note that your date literal refers to `11-Jan-2017`

Comment: (i,12) refers to the date column thats why i used that. what would be the correct datatype to point out the date column?

Comment: yup, i know it refers to 11-jan-2017. I wanted the code to read as dd/mm/yyyy so it that case it would be 1-nov-2017 .

Comment: I've already described how Excel stores dates in my first comment. In Excel, a decimal number is stored as a Double. Do an internet search if you need more details.  Why do you want code to *"read as dd/mm/yyyy"*?  What does that even mean?  You can enter it as a string in your code, but then doing the comparisons with the worksheet cells would become much more difficult, inefficient and time-consuming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `#date#` notation directly, VBA expects it in `mm/DD/yyyy` format.

Comment: @ili_sophia Nope. It's date literal and it can't be changed.

Comment: so is the only way for is to change my external workbook date to mm/dd/yyyy?

Comment: @ili_sophia You don't have to use date literal. Instead, use `Date` variable: `Dim dt As Date: dt = DateSerial(Year:=2018, Month:=1, Day:=2)`

Answer (score 0):

To test if a date on your worksheet is in the month of November 2017:

```
If arr(i, 12) >= #11/1/2017# And arr(i, 12) <= #11/30/2017# Then
   'do whatever
End If
```

So long as the dates in Excel are "real dates", the format of the date in the worksheet cell is irrelevant.

If the dates in Excel are text, you will need to convert them to real dates before you do the comparison.  Whether you do that on the worksheet, or in your code, is irrelevant.

For the date literal in your code, you can substitute other variables that resolve to a VBA Date data type.  Note that if you convert a String, the String must be in an **unambiguous format** (one that can only be interpreted one way).

```
DateSerial(2017, 11, 1)
CDate("2017-11-01")
CDate("1 Nov 2017")
```